# How to select ARIMA model with cyclic ACF?

Tags: arima, stationarity, acf-pacf, eviews

My annual time series has following ACF/PACF structure.

[image]

Based on what ARIMA model should be selected here? Exponential decreasing of ACF --> AR(4) probably? Or because of periodical ACF maybe SMA? Or because of signifiant 1st and 8th PACF --> SAR? Or because it is an annual time series I should not consider seasonal models? What is the best approach here, please?

Time series is stationery.

Time series plot:
[image]

Comment: Your ACF has a periodicity of length about 10. Is there a reason to suspect a recurring seasonal cycle of length 10 in your data? If so, SARIMA looks like a good bet. Failing that, I would trust a modern approach using information criteria (as implemented, e.g., in `forecast::auto.arima()` for R) much more than the Box-Jenkins approach.

Comment: Yeah it seems so. I added time series plot. If I remember correctly, our teacher said that we should consider using seasonal models only if we have montly or quarterly time series - that is why I am not sure if it is possible to use it also for yearly time series.

Comment: What does this data represent? Is there some natural reason for an approx 10 year cycle? Maybe look into spectral analysis ...

Comment: Yeah, the data is from here https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Canadian_lynx_data